# Subprocess readline gets stuck

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I am trying to build a terminal that works based on user input. I managed to get the output but readline() hangs after the output is generated. Is there anyway to stop readline after the user command executes. I have added a small example function to demonstrate the issue:

```
def communicate_with_subprocess(process, command):
    try:
        # Send the command to the subprocess
        process.stdin.write(command + '\n')
        process.stdin.flush()

        lines = []

        # Read the output from the subprocess
        for _line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
            if _line == '':
                break
            lines.append(_line)

        return lines

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error executing command '{command}': {e}")
        return None

# Example usage:
subprocess_instance = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

try:
    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter a command (type 'exit' to quit): ")

        if user_input.lower() == 'exit':
            print("Exiting...")
            break

        output = communicate_with_subprocess(subprocess_instance, user_input)
        print("Output:", output)

finally:
    subprocess_instance.terminate()
    subprocess_instance.wait()
```

The goal is to integrate it into a Django web application so if there any alternative solution that doesn't involve subprocess, that works too.

Comment: Are you sure you want to give a user direct control over a shell in your system? From a security point of view this is a.... very, very, very debatable decision...

Comment: Not exactly, I want to do some sort of santization or sandboxing before executing any command. However, i do want them to interact through the web shell for the functionality to work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I digged more into it. What you want to do is not possible.

The problem is the line `process.stdout.readline`. This waits indefinitely (as you have expirienced) if there is nothing left to read in your subprocess. Usually this is not a problem, since you shut your subprocess down after you have given your commands. But you want to keep it open, hence how should your reading process (main script/Django) know that there is nothing left to print out from your subprocess? Maybe you have startet a long operation that only produces outputs every 10 minutes. So the mechanic is simple: if you call `readline` it waits indefinitly for anything to be returned.

OK..., now what?

You have several options:

- Close your subprocess, after each call (@see [**communicate**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)) and created every time a new one.
- You may keep a single open shell process, but you have to communicate in a different way, because of the problem described above.

  - You may do it [**asynchronously**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html)
  - You keep your current code, but start a second thread that simple polls everything from your shell-process and puts this into a list that you then finally may read (@see [**A non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in Python**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/a-non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python))

### Last thoughts

I still strongly recommend considering another approach. There is almost no chance you may "sanitize" arbitrary user input, to prevent him creating harmful actions/commands. Unless you trust your users 110%, you should consider hardcoding your commands, and give your user this limited choice.